# mySQL SUM NOT IN with exemption

Tags: mysql

I have a TABLE Status:

| Status | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| Y | 1 |
| N | 1 |
| U | 1 |
| X | 1 |
| Y | 2 |
| N | 2 |
| N | 2 |
| N | 4 |
| N | 5 |

I want to SUM all the Status `NOT IN (Y,U,X)` but I also dont want to include Status `N` that has a Reason value of `2` and `5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following logic:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Reason)  -- sum is 5 for the sample data you provided
FROM Status
WHERE Status NOT IN ('U', 'X', 'Y') AND (Status <> 'N' OR Reason NOT IN (2, 5));
```

### Demo

Comment: @daniel.chan I see two tuples being retained `(N, 1)` and `(N, 4)`.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: the problem is there might be other reason that we dont know. All we know is NOT  2 and 5

Answer (score 1):

Try those lines of code maybe help you. The table name must same as your table name.

```
SELECT SUM(Reason)
FROM table_name
WHERE Reason < 2;
```